# assign new value for each unique value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, group-by

Input table

```
ID.  Col1.   
1.    TARGET.   
2.    A
3.    A
4.    TARGET.
5.    A
6.    A
7.    TARGET
```

Desired Output:

```
ID.  Col1.       Col2
1.   TARGET.     1
2.   A.          1
3.   A.          1
4.   TARGET.     2
5.   A.          2
6.   A.          2
7.   TARGET.     3
```

Comment: What's the logic in your expect result?

Comment: thnx for editing...was nt able to use Ctrl +K using phn..plz tell if that's also possible using phn...

Comment: for every next TARGET ..logic should assign a new value ..which should be in sequence..

Comment: Which compatibility mode are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `apply` :

```
select t.*, t1.Col2
from table t outer apply
     ( select count(*) as Col2
       from table t1
       where t1.id <= t.id and t1.col1 = 'TARGET.'
     ) t1;
```

However, cumulative sum is also one is good approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Target' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM @a
```

`SUM(..) OVER (ORDER BY .. )` **Equal** `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY .. ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

[OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: it's giving an error...incorrect syntax near 'order'

Comment: sql version? tag sql-server-2012